# python-pptx not accepting StringIo file type when using with matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, python-pptx

I am trying to create some graphs using matplotlib and then save them to ppt file using python-pptx without saving the image file to disk.

If i see [documentation](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shapes.html) of python-pptx i can see that `add_picture()` accepts a file like object but still i get this error:

```
  File "a.py", line 39, in <module>
    pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(image_stream, left, top)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/shapes/shapetree.py", line 496, in add_picture
    image_part, rId = self.part.get_or_add_image_part(image_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/parts/slide.py", line 42, in get_or_add_image_part
    image_part = self._package.get_or_add_image_part(image_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/package.py", line 50, in get_or_add_image_part
    return self._image_parts.get_or_add_image_part(image_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/package.py", line 161, in get_or_add_image_part
    image_part = ImagePart.new(self._package, image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/parts/image.py", line 44, in new
    partname = package.next_image_partname(image.ext)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/util.py", line 136, in get_prop_value
    value = f(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/parts/image.py", line 238, in ext
    format = self._format
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/parts/image.py", line 273, in _format
    return self._pil_props[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/util.py", line 136, in get_prop_value
    value = f(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pptx/parts/image.py", line 282, in _pil_props
    pil_image = PIL_Image.open(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2572, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x7f30d72a92d8>
```

this is my code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from StringIO import StringIO


from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches


image_stream = StringIO()


# plot a simple graph
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

# saving image file from matplotlib to memory
plt.savefig(image_stream)



prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

left = top = Inches(1)

## this line throws error, but why ????????
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(image_stream, left, top)


prs.save('test.pptx')
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to reposition the cursor of the StringIO object back at the beginning of the "file" before sending it to `.add_picture()`:

```
image_stream.seek(0)
picture = slide.shapes.add_picture(image_stream, left, top)
```

The write operation leaves the cursor at the end of the file (ready for additional write operations). However, the `.add_picture()` code can only call `.read()` to get the contents (`.seek()` is not available on all file-like objects), so you must reposition the cursor before the call.

Comment: just one more problem i am having is the image that is being saved to ppt is in low resolution but when i save it to disk i get a hig res image. could it be format related? i tried passing `forat='svg'` to add_picture() but i get the same error as above

Comment: That's really a separate question @anekix. If you post it with the 'python-pptx' tag, I'll see it. Maybe something like 'python-pptx .add_picture() produces low-resolution image'.

Comment: i will post it as a separate question. thanks again.